# onTouchListener calling method with if statement but sticks with one value

Tags: java, android, ontouch

I'm calling this method through a MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, but the values don't change as movement occurs. It sticks with just the first value pressed on the first touch. It's most likely to do with the if statement I have here not exiting the loop, but I could do with some help

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //_gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    long timeElapsed = 0L;
    int eventAction = event.getAction();
    String number = "";
    String letter = "";
    String join = "";
    int iTo = getIndexOfButton(v);

    // you may need the x/y location
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    String position = "";

    // put your code in here to handle the event
    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("Chess", "Down");
            timeElapsed = event.getDownTime();

            break;//return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("Chess", "Up");
            timeElapsed = event.getDownTime() - timeElapsed;
            if (timeElapsed == 2000) {
                //v.performClick();
                Log.d("Chess", "perform click");
            }
            timeElapsed = 0L;

            break;//return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            respondCoordinates(v);


    }
    // tell the View to redraw the Canvas
    //invalidate();

    return false;//super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public Boolean respondCoordinates(View v){

    int iTo = getIndexOfButton(v);
    String join = "";
    String letter = "";
    String number = "";
    //boolean moveActive = true;

        if ((iTo >= 0) && (iTo <= 7)) {
            number = "8";
            if (iTo == 0) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 1) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 2) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 3) {
                letter = "d";

            } else if (iTo == 4) {
                letter = "e";

            } else if (iTo == 5) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 6) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 7) {
                letter = "h";
            }


        } else if ((iTo >= 8) && (iTo <= 15)) {
            number = "7";
            if (iTo == 8) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 9) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 10) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 11) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 12) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 13) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 14) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 15) {
                letter = "h";
            }

        } else if ((iTo >= 16) && (iTo <= 23)) {
            number = "6";
            if (iTo == 16) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 17) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 18) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 19) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 20) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 21) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 22) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 23) {
                letter = "h";
            }

        } else if ((iTo >= 24) && (iTo <= 31)) {
            number = "5";
            if (iTo == 24) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 25) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 26) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 27) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 28) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 29) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 30) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 31) {
                letter = "h";
            }

        } else if ((iTo >= 32) && (iTo <= 39)) {
            number = "4";
            if (iTo == 32) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 33) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 34) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 35) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 36) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 37) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 38) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 39) {
                letter = "h";
            }

        } else if ((iTo >= 40) && (iTo <= 47)) {
            number = "3";
            if (iTo == 40) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 41) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 42) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 43) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 44) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 45) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 46) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 47) {
                letter = "h";
            }

        } else if ((iTo >= 48) && (iTo <= 55)) {
            number = "2";
            if (iTo == 48) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 49) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 50) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 51) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 52) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 53) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 54) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 55) {
                letter = "h";
            }

        } else if ((iTo >= 56) && (iTo <= 63)) {
            number = "1";
            if (iTo == 56) {
                letter = "a";
            } else if (iTo == 57) {
                letter = "b";
            } else if (iTo == 58) {
                letter = "c";
            } else if (iTo == 59) {
                letter = "d";
            } else if (iTo == 60) {
                letter = "e";
            } else if (iTo == 61) {
                letter = "f";
            } else if (iTo == 62) {
                letter = "g";
            } else if (iTo == 63) {
                letter = "h";
            }


        }

    join = letter + number;
    Log.d("Chess", join);



    return false;

}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should change the returned value in onTouch function and if the event action was MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN you should return true instead of false to get the other events.